# Algebraic indices in the sigma symbol

Tags: analysis

$ \sum\limits_{x + y=0}^n  1/(x!.y!)$

for example let n = 3.

Then should we right down all the combinations then sum them does this means that ?:

$ \sum\limits_{x + y=0}^3  1/(x!.y!) = $

$ x + y = 0 $  1 case => 1/0!.0!

$ x + y = 1 $  2 cases => 1/1!.0! + 1/0.1!

$ x + y = 2 $  3 cases => 1/1!.1! + 1/2.0!  + 1/0!.2!

$ x + y = 3 $  4 cases => 1/0!.3! + 1/1.2!  + 1/2!.1!  + 1/3!.0!
...

Comment: Be careful: do you mean $$\frac{1}{x!y!}$$ or $$\frac{y!}{x!}?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$